# restful service as both http and https - iis urlrewrite

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, wcf-rest

Our application is developed in MVC 4 with WCF services. We have installed SSL and website is working fine (default https), But our Restful services are ***not** working in **http*** its showing ***HTTP 404 The resource cannot be found***.

I am using url rewrite as :

```
<rule name="Https Except Service" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/(wsserv\.svc.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/(rest\.svc.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Our Serice some Get uri as :

```
/rest.svc/getallcategories
/rest.svc/user-id/cat-id
/rest.svc/user-id/cat-id/sub-catid
```

service `rest.svc`  is working fine in https but it is not working with http, on http request its showing error HTTP 404 the resource cannot be found.

How to make `rest.svc` service accessilbe in both http and https ?

Comment: Check what FRT says about those 404 errors, www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Is your project deployed in IIS?

Comment: Yes, in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and hosted in iis

Comment: Have you added http binding for the service in IIS?

Comment: it is restful and http get and https get are allowed